# Jquery click trigger gives error 'Maximum call stack size exceeded '

Tags: jquery

I know I might get bunch of downvotes but I don't care, crap like this drives me insane. Here's what I got:

jq:

```
function attFile(){
   $("#theFileInput").trigger('click');
};
```

html:

```
<a href="#" id="attachfile" onclick="attFile();">
<input type="file" id="theFileInput" style="display:none" />
```

And it doesn't work. I've check entire stackoverflow, I've used jsfiddles from people that actually work and they fail here. For instance:

```
$('#attachfile').click(functcion () {
$("#theFileInput").trigger('click'); // or triggerHandler or click()
});
```

or

```
function attFile(event){
event.preventDefault();
$("#theFileInput").trigger('click');
};
```

It all fails. Event will give me "call to undefined", while rest gives me **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** If I break it with `alert("jq please");` at the first line, depending on the code I use, one will loop forever, while others will show the alert but not click the damn file input.

Comment: there is a typo: `fucntcion`

Comment: its not fixed - `functcion` in the third code snippet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Html:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="attachfile">Click on me </a>
<input type="file" id="theFileInput" style="display:none" />
```

**JS:**

```
$('#attachfile').click(function () {
$("#theFileInput").trigger('click');
});
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/eR64x/)**

Comment: Yeah.. My `<a>` tag was empty :) Thank you

Comment: u r welcome. :) close that Q, as resolved. so we can focus on next. hehe )

Comment: do you mind giving me some explantion on this `javascript:void(0);` why do we need to use this? @EugeneP.