# jQuery child file upload click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to run the code as and its working

```
<input type="file" />
<div class="image">

</div>
$('.image').click(function() {

    $('input').trigger('click');
});
```

Now, I want the code as

```
<div class="image">
<input type="file" />    
</div>
$('.image').click(function() {
    $(this).find('input').trigger('click');
});
```

and, I am not sure why this is not working.

Sample Fiddle is here. http://jsfiddle.net/CSvjw/1538/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery click trigger gives error 'Maximum call stack size exceeded '](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493155/jquery-click-trigger-gives-error-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem is:**

[image: Error: Too much recursion]

**Solution:**

```js
$('.image').click(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).is('input')) {
    $(this).find('input').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```css
input[type=file] {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
.image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
  <input type="file" />
</div>
```

Comment: awesome, this works. I am not sure who is the person clicking on -1's to all answers.